# Aggregated query without GROUP BY

Tags: php, sql, mysql, group-by

This query seems to work perfectly on my older machine. However, on my new machine with MySQL 5.7.14 and PHP 5.6.25 it throws the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated
> query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains
> nonaggregated column 'pixel_perfect.users.id'; this is incompatible
> with sql_mode=only_full_group_by' in C:\wamp64\www

Here is what my query looks like:

```
$sql="SELECT id, password, COUNT(id) AS count FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1";

$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Why am I getting this error now and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: count() is an aggregation function in mysql. It can only be used when attempting to aggregate the values of a column across all rows. It cannot be used along with getting other values on a per row basis as you are attempting. You can simple count the results returned if you need a count.

Comment: A `user` only has 1 id right so couldn't you just `group by` the `id`?

Comment: @chris85 True, yet it'd be interesting to find out the reason why their code failed. I for one am a bit baffled.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A [change was made in version 5.7.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) where it will now, by default, reject queries in which you aggregate using a function (`sum`, `avg`, `max`, etc.) in the `SELECT` clause and fail to put the non-aggregated fields in the `GROUP BY` clause. This behavior is part and parcel to every other RDBMS and MySQL is finally jumping on board.

You have two options:

1. You can change the MySQL settings to default to the old behavior to allow not-so-great queries like this. Information can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)
2. You can fix your query

Option 2 would look something like:

```
SELECT id, password, COUNT(id) AS count 
FROM users 
WHERE email = :email 
GROUP BY id, password 
LIMIT 1
```

It's also important to note that excluding a non-aggregated column from the GROUP BY clause is permitted in 5.7.5 and newer version in the event that the unaggregated column has been limited to a single value (such as a filter in the WHERE clause). See the link above for examples of this allowed exception.

Comment: So in other words, they're forced to do a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- They don't HAVE to do a GROUP BY. They could also toss an aggregate function around the remaining fields like `SELECT max(id), max(password), count(id)` would probably be closer to the arbitrary nature of the same query without the `GROUP BY` but it feels very wrong.

Comment: So... is this a thing simply because it's a thing? I mean what does this have to do with the Relational Calculus* RDBMS's are based on? I fail to see how this assists in maintaining data integrity. I assume I'm missing something but maybe not? 
*(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_calculus)

Comment: @MER It's everything to do with data integrity. Imagine a simple table as `id | parent_id` and two rows: `1 | 3`, `2 | 3`. And you issue: `SELECT I'd, parent_id FROM table GROUP BY parent_id;`. Old mysql isnt going to error that like every other RDBMS, it will spit out a single record. But... Which `id` will it choose? `1` or `2`? Totally up to chance. You wrap this in an app and your user gets back 1 and runs again and gets 2 and then runs against and gets 1... Nonsense.

Answer (score 37):

Its a little late but I just ran into this error.

This command might be useful for anyone else who runs into the same error

```
     mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

More information about this can be found at [Table Plus](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-turn-off-only-full-group-by.html) and other links quoted above by **JNevill**.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Yeah yeah, sweeping the dirt under the rug is surely useful when your task is to clean the room.

Comment: Life saver answer

Comment: It is wise to use `GROUP BY` in this kind of situation.

Comment: I have a huge website built in CakePHP 2 and this helped me to sweep the dirt under the rug! ;)

Comment: @YourCommonSense It is when you are expecting guests at any moment, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest answer, in config/database.php make sure to set strict => true to strict => false for the mysql settings.

This will allow for less than strict queries at a cost of security for normal well-formed sql calls (still not 100% secure), but will allow for the use of other sql calls that could be in-secure if written improperly.

Comment: So we enforce a group by for ... security??!
Sorry not challenging your statement but that it seems to be generally accepted.
I guess so you can't inject a subselect or other SQL command inside a concat() or similar? ... hmmm I think that's a very thin argument... As you mentioned, the real security is in what actually runs the queries... I mean sure there should be an effort made but this one has always seemed silly to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change ur SQL mode to default..  it will execute without error
The SQL mode defines the syntax of the query. If you using ONLY_FULLY_GROUPBY you have to write a query with group by for all aggregator functions

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error recently,

The below steps helped me and saved me a lot of time.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = (SELECT 
REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
SET SESSION sql_mode = (SELECT 
REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

Or

The below also works:

`mysql > SET @@sql_mode = sys.list_drop(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY');`

More information about this can be found at (https://database.guide/fix-error-1140-in-aggregated-query-without-group-by-expression-1-of-select-list-contains-nonaggregated-column-in-mysql/)

Thanks