# A Database Error Occurred Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm on my website setting up a new database for a user dashboard an I run into this problem:

[image: Database]

This is a MySQL Server. I set it up as MySQLI as MySQL Would not seem to work

Columns was added

[image: All Colums Added]

Any tips on how to solve this? I had looked at all my tables but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?  It looks like probably just one of them

Comment: Definitely got some creepy backticks. Must be MySQL.

Comment: It also just looks like you need to review syntax with Grouping...     once you decide which database you're really using,  you will probably be referred to other questions on this basic syntax

Comment: In MySQL 5.7+ "only_full_group_by" is on by default. That means if you aren't aggregating a column in your SELECT clause, it MUST be present in your group by. This is how every other RDBMS works, so MySQL finally got on board.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregated query without GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481869/aggregated-query-without-group-by). If you share the SQL that generated this error we can help rewrite, otherwise check out the duplicate it has a link on how to turn off the "only_full_group_by" option, although I would push to fix the SQL so you never have to monkey with it again.

Comment: Nooooo don't even mention to turn "only_full_group_by" option off @JNevill

Comment: Yes, definitely always include your actual query and database table structure  (or an equivalent with mock data if necessary for your situation).

Comment: @RaymondNijland LOL! I know I know I know. BUT... sometimes when you are using an application (Such as MythTVBackend) and they haven't updated the code base to account for this default, you have no choice (Like MythTVBackend... ok maybe they've updated it by now, but that was a confusing couple of hours for me a year or two ago). Toggle a setting or become a contributor and make a pull request and deal with some open source politics.

Comment: All the columns was in  https://i.imgur.com/Qq9Z1wx.png

Answer (score 0):

Located at `/etc/mysql/` directory in a standard installation.

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then add the following lines to the end of its content (you need to press “insert” key before typing in “vim”)

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

then save the file. (press “Esc” and then type “:wq” in “vim” to save and exit)

Once done restart the MySQL server by running

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: That is what i did ? Still does not work https://i.imgur.com/Qq9Z1wx.png

Comment: if like that you need to replace your mysqld sql_mode

Comment: That is how i have got it or what it is in https://i.imgur.com/57e0Tej.png

Comment: is my.cnf not in this locate /etc/mysql/my.cnf in your server