# ERROR 1140 (42000) In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1

Tags: mysql, sql

My question comes from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/problem

Below is the input data:

[image]

The question asks to find the maximum earnings (months * salary) and the total count of row that has the maximum earnings.

My try is:

```
select distinct salary*months, count(*)
from employee
where salary*months = (select max(salary*months) from employee)
```

This gives me the error message:

> ERROR 1140 (42000) at line 6: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'run_byli4vf7yqz.employee.salary'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Any suggestion why I failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `select distinct`:

```
select (e.salary * e.months), count(*)
from employee e
where (e.salary * e.months) = (select max(e2.salary * e2.months)
                               from employee e2
                              )
group by (e.salary * e.months);
```

The message is pretty clear.  You have `count(*)` so your query is an aggregation query.  However, you have an unaggregated column, so MySQL is confused:  do you want an aggregation or not?  Hence the error.

You can also write this as:

```
select (e.salary * e.months), count(*)
from employee e
group by (e.salary * e.months)
order by (e.salary * e.months) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481869/aggregated-query-without-group-by/43482023)