# The GROUP BY statement in my SQL query failed to get data

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm writing an SQL query using GROUP BY, but on executing the GROUP BY statement, I get an error.

```sql
$data = DB::table('artisantypes') 
->SELECT(DB::Raw("artisantypes.max_seat as max_size,3956 * 2 *  ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(('$current_lat' - artisans.driver_lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2)+ COS('$current_lat' * pi()/180 ) * COS(artisans.driver_lat *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(('$current_lng' - artisans.driver_lng) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))  as distance,artisans.driver_lat,artisans.driver_lng" )) 
  ->leftjoin('artisans','artisantypes.id', '=','artisans.car_id' ) 
  ->WHERE([['artisantypes.id' ,'=', $car_type],['artisans.artstatus', '=' , 0]]) 
  ->groupby('artisans.id') 
  ->HAVING('distance' ,'<', 25) 
  ->orderby ('distance', 'ASC' ) 
  ->LIMIT( 0,1) 
  ->get();
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'sloyd.artisantypes.max_seat' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: Any column in the SELECT portion of your SQL that is not being aggregated by an aggregation formula (`sum()`, `max()`, etc) must be contained in your GROUP BY clause. This restriction was added in MySQL 5.7 and can be disabled by flipping your ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY flag on your mysql server. Although, I would just fix your query. [See here for more information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregated query without GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481869/aggregated-query-without-group-by)