# why i am getting error like this ? Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains non aggregated column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  vp.visitor_id , vp.name ,vp.email ,count(n.notification_id) 
from visitor_profile vp join notification n on n.receiver_id = vp.visitor_id 
where n.status = 0 
  and vp.visitor_id in  (66578,66579);
```

Comment: You have no `group by` clause - just like the error tells you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle (PL/SQL)?

Comment: Some related / useful reading: 1) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html   and 2) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html   ... This is the 8.0 documentation.  Most, if not all, of this applies to 5.7.

Comment: The error message looks like MySQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregated query without GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481869/aggregated-query-without-group-by)

Comment: why?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html  mySQL group by extensions  and how the default for this extension is set in earlier versions of mySQL vs now.

Answer (score 0):

Columns that aren't aggregated must be specified in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT vp.visitor_id,
       vp.name,
       vp.email,
       COUNT(n.notification_id)
FROM visitor_profile vp
JOIN notification n ON n.receiver_id = vp.visitor_id
WHERE n.status = 0
  AND vp.visitor_id IN(66578, 66579)
GROUP BY vp.visitor_id, vp.name, vp.email;   --> missing
```

Comment: If `visitor_id` is the primary key, so the other columns are functionally dependent, you only need `GROUP BY vp.visitor_id`

Comment: Aha. I was *fooled* by PL/SQL tag which is Oracle's procedural extension of its SQL, and - in Oracle - you have to specify **all** non-aggregated columns. Thank you, @Barmar.

Comment: Keep in mind this is mysql which depending on version, may have the default set to allow for group by extensions.  So it may help to answer the "Why" by indicating in earlier versions of mySQL this was defaulted a different way than current versions, which explains why now.  and then reference the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: A MySQL extension permits a column that does not appear in the GROUP BY list to be named in the select list. (For information about nonaggregated columns and GROUP BY, see Section 12.20.3, “MySQL Handling of GROUP BY”.) In this case, the server is free to choose any value from this nonaggregated column in summary rows, and this includes the extra rows added by WITH ROLLUP. For example, in the following query, country is a nonaggregated column that does not appear in the GROUP BY ...

Answer (score -1):

Change sql mode to full groupBy by running query below

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: I disagree with this. We should stop recommending to disable ONLY_FULLY_GROUP_BY. It's there to prevent writing invalid queries. It's better to fix the query so it's valid.