# MySQL #1140 - I want to display the minimum salary, it gives this error

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display the minimum salary, it gives this error
I have to take out one person who gets the lowest salary not using group by

```
SELECT
    MIN(salary) as 'min_salary',
    name_surname
FROM
    player,
    contracts
WHERE
    player.id = contracts.id
LIMIT 0, 50
```

MySql error:

> #1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column
> 'football_club.player.name_surname'; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: **Don't use** the ancient comma-separated `FROM` clause - instead you need to use explicit `JOIN` criteria.

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to use a GROUP BY clause in your query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregated query without GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481869/aggregated-query-without-group-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm editing the answer as now the question is more clear.

You can extract the persons with the lowest salaries with:

```
SELECT
    salary,
    name_surname
FROM
    player
WHERE salary = (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM player)
```

Of course you'll have more than one row if more player has the lowest salary

Comment: I have to take out one person who gets the lowest salary

Comment: Just use LIMIT 1 if you want only one (chosen randomly). This is also achievable by using ROW_NUMBER function and keeping the first row matching the lowest salary.